# Handling POST request via Socket in Java

Tags: java, sockets, http, post, request

I'm trying to handle a simple POST Request in Java using a Socket. 
I can receive the request header and answer the request without any problem, but I certainly can not get the body of the request.

I read somewhere that I'd need to open a second InputStream to achive this, but this doesn't really makes sense to me. Do you have any tips on how to get the request body?

This is what I basically use to get the header:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                clientSocket.getInputStream()));

char[] inputBuffer = new char[INPUT_BUFFER_LENGTH];

int inputMessageLength = in.read(inputBuffer, 0,
                INPUT_BUFFER_LENGTH);

String inputMessage = new String(inputBuffer, 0, inputMessageLength);
```

So, the message I get is something like:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_45
Host: localhost:5555
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
```

But I can't get the parameters of the POST request.

*Edit:*

So it turned out I just had **INPUT_BUFFER_LENGTH** up high enough (I know, shame on me).
So as it worked I changed my *ServerSocket* to *SSLServerSocket* and tried again to send a request with a *HttpsUrlConnection* from Java, now I have the same problem again (already checked the buffer), getting something like this:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_45
Host: localhost:5555
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Connection: keep-alive
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 128

*Missing Body*
```

It turned out I only get this when sending requests with my Java-Client - Sending requests from Chrome, etc are working fine - so I assume I got something wrong in my code.
This is what I use to send the request:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", ...);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", ...);

SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory
            .getDefault();

String url = "https://...";
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory);

con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setDoOutput(true);

OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());

writer.write(*Some String*);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

Any tips on what might be wrong with my code?

Comment: A second input stream? There's a single input stream per socket. Just read it.

Comment: Anywhere where you read about opening a second input stream you're reading grade A BS. If the body data is binary, using a Reader of any kind cannot possibly work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you have shown is not the correct way to read HTTP requests.

First off, Java has its own [`HttpServer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html) and [`HttpsServer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpsServer.html) classes.  You should consider using them.

Otherwise, you have to implement the HTTP protocol manually. You need to read the input line-by-line until you reach an empty line indicating the end of the request headers, then look at the headers you have read, in particular the `Transfer-Encoding` and `Content-Length` headers, to know how to read the remaining bytes of the request, per [RFC 2616 Section 4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4):

> 4.4 Message Length

> The transfer-length of a message is the length of the message-body as
> it appears in the message; that is, after any transfer-codings have
> been applied. When a message-body is included with a message, the
> transfer-length of that body is determined by one of the following
> (in order of precedence):

> 1. Any response message which "MUST NOT" include a message-body (such
>    as the 1xx, 204, and 304 responses and any response to a HEAD
>    request) is always terminated by the first empty line after the
>    header fields, regardless of the entity-header fields present in
>    the message.

> 2. If a Transfer-Encoding header field (section 14.41) is present and
>    has any value other than "identity", then the transfer-length is
>    defined by use of the "chunked" transfer-coding (section 3.6),
>    unless the message is terminated by closing the connection.

> 3. If a Content-Length header field (section 14.13) is present, its
>    decimal value in OCTETs represents both the entity-length and the
>    transfer-length. The Content-Length header field MUST NOT be sent
>    if these two lengths are different (i.e., if a Transfer-Encoding
>    header field is present). If a message is received with both a
>    Transfer-Encoding header field and a Content-Length header field,
>    the latter MUST be ignored.

> 4. If the message uses the media type "multipart/byteranges", and the
>    ransfer-length is not otherwise specified, then this self-
>    elimiting media type defines the transfer-length. This media type
>    UST NOT be used unless the sender knows that the recipient can arse
>    it; the presence in a request of a Range header with ultiple byte-
>    range specifiers from a 1.1 client implies that the lient can parse
>    multipart/byteranges responses.

> A range header might be forwarded by a 1.0 proxy that does not
> understand multipart/byteranges; in this case the server MUST
> delimit the message using methods defined in items 1,3 or 5 of
> this section.

> 5. By the server closing the connection. (Closing the connection
>    cannot be used to indicate the end of a request body, since that
>    would leave no possibility for the server to send back a response.)

> For compatibility with HTTP/1.0 applications, HTTP/1.1 requests
> containing a message-body MUST include a valid Content-Length header
> field unless the server is known to be HTTP/1.1 compliant. If a
> request contains a message-body and a Content-Length is not given,
> the server SHOULD respond with 400 (bad request) if it cannot
> determine the length of the message, or with 411 (length required) if
> it wishes to insist on receiving a valid Content-Length.

> All HTTP/1.1 applications that receive entities MUST accept the
> "chunked" transfer-coding (section 3.6), thus allowing this mechanism
> to be used for messages when the message length cannot be determined
> in advance.

> Messages MUST NOT include both a Content-Length header field and a
> non-identity transfer-coding. If the message does include a non-
> identity transfer-coding, the Content-Length MUST be ignored.

> When a Content-Length is given in a message where a message-body is
> allowed, its field value MUST exactly match the number of OCTETs in
> the message-body. HTTP/1.1 user agents MUST notify the user when an
> invalid length is received and detected.

Try something more like this (semi-pseudo code):

```
String readLine(BufferedInputStream in)
{
    // HTTP carries both textual and binary elements.
    // Not using BufferedReader.readLine() so it does
    // not "steal" bytes from BufferedInputStream...

    // HTTP itself only allows 7bit ASCII characters
    // in headers, but some header values may be
    // further encoded using RFC 2231 or 5987 to
    // carry Unicode characters ...

    InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(in, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char c;
    while ((c = r.read()) >= 0) {
        if (c == '\n') break;
        if (c == '\r') {
            c = r.read();
            if ((c < 0) || (c == '\n')) break;
            sb.append('\r');
        }
        sb.append(c);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

...

BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

String request = readLine(in);
// extract method, resource, and version...

String line;

do
{
    line = readLine(in);
    if (line.isEmpty()) break;
    // store line in headers list...
}
while (true);

// parse headers list...

if (request method has a message-body) // POST, etc
{
    if ((request version >= 1.1) &&
        (Transfer-Encoding header is present) &&
        (Transfer-Encoding != "identity"))
    {
        // read chunks...
        do
        {
            line = readLine(in); // read chunk header
            int size = extract value from line;
            if (size == 0) break;
            // use in.read() to read the specified
            // number of bytes into message-body...
            readLine(in); // skip trailing line break
        }
        while (true);

        // read trailing headers...
        line = readLine(in);
        while (!line.isEmpty())
        {
            // store line in headers list, updating
            // any existing header as needed...
        }

        // parse headers list again ...
    }
    else if (Content-Length header is present)
    {
        // use in.read() to read the specified
        // number of bytes into message-body...
    }
    else if (Content-Type is "multipart/...")
    {
        // use readLine(in) and in.read() as needed
        // to read/parse/decode MIME encoded data into
        // message-body until terminating MIME boundary
        // is reached...
    }
    else
    {
        // fail the request...
    }
}

// process request and message-body as needed..
```

Comment: Thanks for all the information. Turned out that in my case I just had to increase the value of my buffer, as I only sent plain text.
But I guess in case of sending raw bytes I'll have to do it "the hard way" like you suggested.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the content is, or how long it is.  HTTP is a **protocol**, you have to follow the protocol in order to receive the content *correctly*.  Java has its own [`HttpServer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html) and [`HttpsServer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpsServer.html) classes. If you don't want to use them, you have to implement the protocol yourself.

Comment: I ended up implementing this the way you said, thanks for your help!