# How to send file to web browser using java sockets?

Tags: java, sockets, http

I'm trying to build a HTTP server in Java out of curiosity.

I know that HTTP uses sockets underneath(correct me if i'm wrong). So started programming initially using `ServerSocket` class.

```
public class Server
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Listening.....");
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(80);
        while(true)
        {
        Socket s = ss.accept();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
        while(sc.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            if(line.equals(""))
                break;
            else
                System.out.println(line);
        }
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
        ps.println("Hello from Server");
        s.close();
        ps.close();
        sc.close();
        }
    }
}
```

(I'm using `Thread` in my actual code to serve multiple users. I've just provided the basic code.)

I'm getting all the headers from the web browser. But how can I send the files and images?

For, simple HTML I can read the file and use `PrintStream` to print it on the web browser.

But how can I send JavaScript, Images etc to the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP has a protocol to it, you need to follow that protocol.  The HTTP 1.1 protocol spec still in wide use is [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) (though it has officially been replaced with newer RFCs [7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230), [7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231), [7232](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232), [7233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233), [7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234), and [7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235)).

In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30908736/65863) to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901173/), I show the *correct* way to read an inbound HTTP request from a Java `Socket` directly.

When sending a reply back, you can use a `PrintStream` or `PrintWriter` to send the response HTTP headers.  However, the body content is sent as raw bytes, based on the format specified by the `Content-Type` and `Transfer-Encoding` response headers.  Typically, you would just send the raw bytes directly to the socket's `OutputStream`, or at least to a `BufferedOutputStream` attached to it.  If you are sending a pre-existing file from disk, regardless of its type, you could just open an `InputStream` for the file and then copy its data directly to the socket's `OutputStream`.  If you are generating data dynamically, then you would send the data to the socket's `OutputStream` using whatever intermediate classes are appropriate.  `Print...` classes are only appropriate for textual data, not binary data, like images.

That being said, Java has its own [HttpServer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html) and [HttpsServer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpsServer.html) classes. You should consider using them.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the same way. You should "print" the raw bytes to the socket's OutputStream.

However, for the browser to be able to understand it, you need to shape your response according to the [HTTP/1.1 protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616). Specifying a `Content-Type` header will tell the browser what it is receiving from you.  Specifying a `Content-Length` header will tell the browser how many bytes it is receiving from you.  Etc.