# Receiving http requests with winsock

Tags: c++, winsock2

For educational purposes I am trying to make a web api in c++. the web api needs to be able to listen for http requests(GET, POST etc.), when it receives a http request it needs to be able to send data back to the client. Because it is for educational purposes I would like to do it without unnecessary libraries. Now the first thing I need to do is make the api able to receive requests and respond on that, after some research on google I found out that winsock is probably the most basic way to setup sockets for windows but I could find very little on receiving http requests.

**My question is**: Is it possible with winsock to receive a http request from the browser, and send data back to the browser?.

Comment: The answer is: yes, of course it is possible. A socket can receive anything from anyone, and send anything to anyone. You will find the specification for HTTP [in RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), this is the protocol you will need to implement with your socket. It shouldn't take more than a month or two, provided you have good C++ skills, a good ability to understand technical specifications, and you already know and understand MIME. If you don't know anything about MIME, on which HTTP is heavily based, see RFC 2045 through 2048 (another 3-4 months). Good luck.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik also if he wants to learn from a "solved example", he would read code from library like `libuv` or `boost::asio`, then try to apply what he understood

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thnx for guiding me in the right direction. The specification is certainly going to help!

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30908736/65863) (though it targets Java, the same *logic* can be applied to C++, too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is, Because HTTP is a protocol that (usually) uses TCP as the underlying transportation protocol.

But trying to build a real HTTP layer on top of a simple win32 socket is a bit too much even for an experienced C++ developer.

Many un-experienced C++ developers would probably dismiss this task as a "well, you just need to read some data, parse the headers, assemble your own HTTP response and send it back".

but.. 
You will have to support

- TLS, with all the nasty private keys/public keys implementation
- Redirection
- Chunked Transfer
- G-Zip transfer

and the list goes on and on..

So practically speaking, if you just want to to accept a socket, read some data and send some basic HTTP response than yes. If you want a reliable, professional HTTP library - probably no.

Comment: I am definitely not looking to create a professional http library. I just want to create a web api specifically for a simple website I created for learning purposes.

Comment: but a web API requires a professional HTTP library.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: Is it possible with winsock to receive a http request from the browser, and send data back to the browser?

Yes. ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can check this page https://github.com/ReneNyffenegger/cpp-webserver to see simple winsock server implementation for HTTP. Web server implementation is not so difficult. Of course you should have time for it.