# Java server socket using writeBytes

Tags: java, sockets, http, server, echo

I'm trying to implement a simple server using Java sockets. The server should echo back the HTTP Request message that the client sends. Thus if I enter http://localhost:8888 in to my browser, I expect to see the HTTP Request message that I sent as plain text in the web page. The code seems to do what I expect it to do, as the browser does display a http message which is the same as what is printed out in cmd when I run the program.

There are some parts of my code I wonder about though, like having:

`out.writeBytes("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"); out.writeBytes("\r\n");`

before my data. Is this enough to be a valid HTTP response?

Is there anything else in my code that doesn't seem to make sense, or could be improved?

Here is the full program which is executed in cmd by "java HTTPEcho 8888" for example, and checked by entering localhost:8888 in your browser, and whatever is printed in cmd should be the same as in the browser.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class HTTPEcho {
    public static void main( String[] args) throws IOException {
        if (args.length != 1) {
                    System.err.println("Usage: java HTTPEcho <port number>");
                    System.exit(1);
        }
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        try (

            ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        ){
            // echo back http request message as response to web browser client

            out.writeBytes("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n");
            out.writeBytes("\r\n");

            String s;
            while ((s = in.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(s);
                out.writeBytes(s + "\r\n");
                if(s.isEmpty()){
                    break;
                }
            }

            out.close();
            in.close();
            connectionSocket.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port "
                            + port + " or listening for a connection");
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The 1-Line HTTP header you output is OK for HTTP 1.0 protocol. If the response is large, then an additional header "Content-Lenght: xxx" with the  number of bytes (not characters!) helps the browser to display a progress bar while receiving the data. An additional header like "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" helps the browser to display the response properly.

Comment: At the very least, you also need to add a `Connection: close` response header, since you are closing the socket at the end of the response: `out.writeBytes("Connection: close\r\n");` And FYI, a `readLine()` loop is not the correct way to read a client's HTTP request, not even close. All your loop is doing is reading the request headers, but not the request body, which may not be empty (for a `GET` request, it will be, though). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30908736/65863).